# Global action listener

Tags: swing

What's wrong with the following code / my assumptions?

First I register the AWT event listener:

```
...
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(this,
    AWTEvent.ACTION_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.ITEM_EVENT_MASK
    );
...
```

Then I expect `eventDispatched(AWTEvent)` get called each time a user selects item from `JComboBox` or `JList`. However, nothing happens. Why?

```
@Override
public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof ItemEvent) {
        System.out.println("ITEM EVENT");   // this is never called
    } else if (event instanceof ActionEvent) {
        System.out.println("ACTION EVENT"); // this is never called
    }
}
```

I know that I can add `ActionListener` to `JComboBox` and `JList`, but I would like to avoid this solutions since I am trying to log user activity, thus the listener should be 'global'.

Comment: why do you think you need a _global_ listener for semantic events like action/item? Sounds fishy ...

Comment: Because I think that the implementation of 'user activity tracker' would be simpler than adding action/item/... listener to each JComponent contained in my GUI.

Comment: singleton-thinking is evil :-) And it's not necessarily user-activity that triggers those _semantic_ events - might happen programatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the feature I am asking for might not be supported:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6292132

Related post:
[How to add global action event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753709/how-to-add-global-action-event-listener)